# Unknown compiler option '@angular/*'

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

i was trying to use sonar cloud to analyse my code using azure devops pipeline

i faced this error, in `Run Code Analysis task` , but the step still passed in the end :

```
14:53:52.353 INFO: Found 1 tsconfig.json file(s): [/home/vsts/work/1/s/tsconfig.json]
##[error]14:53:52.489 ERROR: Unknown compiler option '@angular/*'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]14:53:52.489 ERROR: Unknown compiler option '@angular/*'.
##[debug]Processed: 14:53:52.489 ERROR: Unknown compiler option '@angular/*'.##vso[task.logissue type=error;]
```

this my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

i'am able to generate the dist file.

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

Remove the offending line

```
"@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
```

As the error suggests, `@angular/*` is not [a valid `compilerOption`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

See also https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options

Comment: thanks for your reply but when i delete this line , multiple error showing in the console

Comment: i've complier and compiler-cli in node_modules folder